# Serialization Concept In Java with Composition

Tags: java

If an object is going to be serialized will it be possible to serialize its data member(which are also objects that is composition).

If yes then in which order the state of those objects will be retrieved?

Comment: Dont care about the Order. You are not able to discover the big-bang of deserialization except readObject/writeObject.

Answer (score 1):

If they are also [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) then, yes otherwise you'll get a [NotSerializableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html). If you explicitly want to not serialize a member object then declare it as `transient`.

Regarding the order, I don't get what you mean by that. If you read a serialized object you'll get it in the exact same state it had at serialization.